# Optimizing access on numpy arrays for numba

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba, accumarray

I recently stumbled upon [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) and thought about replacing some homemade C extensions with more elegant autojitted python code. Unfortunately I wasn't happy, when I tried a first, quick benchmark. It seems like numba is not doing much better than ordinary python here, though I would have expected nearly C-like performance:

```
from numba import jit, autojit, uint, double
import numpy as np
import imp
import logging
logging.getLogger('numba.codegen.debug').setLevel(logging.INFO)

def sum_accum(accmap, a):
    res = np.zeros(np.max(accmap) + 1, dtype=a.dtype)
    for i in xrange(len(accmap)):
        res[accmap[i]] += a[i]
    return res

autonumba_sum_accum = autojit(sum_accum)
numba_sum_accum = jit(double[:](int_[:], double[:]), 
                      locals=dict(i=uint))(sum_accum)

accmap = np.repeat(np.arange(1000), 2)
np.random.shuffle(accmap)
accmap = np.repeat(accmap, 10)
a = np.random.randn(accmap.size)

ref = sum_accum(accmap, a)
assert np.all(ref == numba_sum_accum(accmap, a))
assert np.all(ref == autonumba_sum_accum(accmap, a))

%timeit sum_accum(accmap, a)
%timeit autonumba_sum_accum(accmap, a)
%timeit numba_sum_accum(accmap, a)

accumarray = imp.load_source('accumarray', '/path/to/accumarray.py')
assert np.all(ref == accumarray.accum(accmap, a))

%timeit accumarray.accum(accmap, a)
```

This gives on my machine:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 52 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 42.2 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 43.5 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 321 us per loop
```

I'm running the latest numba version from pypi, 0.11.0. Any suggestions, how to fix the code, so it runs reasonably fast with numba?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@autojit
def numbaMax(arr):
    MAX = arr[0]
    for i in arr:
        if i > MAX:
            MAX = i
    return MAX

@autojit
def autonumba_sum_accum2(accmap, a):
    res = np.zeros(numbaMax(accmap) + 1)
    for i in xrange(len(accmap)):
        res[accmap[i]] += a[i]
    return res

10 loops, best of 3: 26.5 ms per loop <- original
100 loops, best of 3: 15.1 ms per loop <- with numba but the slow numpy max
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.9 µs per loop <- with numbamax
```

Answer (score 6):

I figured out myself. numba wasn't able to determine the type of the result of `np.max(accmap)`, even if the type of accmap was set to int. This somehow slowed down everything, but the fix is easy:

```
@autojit(locals=dict(reslen=uint))
def sum_accum(accmap, a):
    reslen = np.max(accmap) + 1
    res = np.zeros(reslen, dtype=a.dtype)
    for i in range(len(accmap)):
        res[accmap[i]] += a[i]
    return res
```

The result is quite impressive, about 2/3 of the C version:

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 192 us per loop
```

**Update 2022:**
The work on this issue led to the python package `numpy_groupies`, which is available here:

https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies

Comment: numba is most effective for pure python code, and numpy arrays. Any special functions it wont be able to accelerate optimally. if you wrote your own max function in pure python, and autojited that, it would probably be faster.

Comment: I had a look into the code of numba. For many numpy functions it determines the output data type correctly by looking at the input and knowing how the function behaves. It's called type inference. This works fine e.g. with `np.sum` and `np.prod`, but min and max are not listed in the code. I filed a bug report for that.